# Как получить значение такой формы в JS или mootools, чтобы передать дальше в PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, json, mootools

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ее HTML:

```
<select name="birthdate[day]" id="birthdate-day" class="date_class">
    <option value="0"> </option>
     .....
</select>
<select name="birthdate[month]" id="birthdate-month" class="date_class">
    <option value="0"></option>
    ..........
</select>
<select name="birthdate[year]" id="birthdate-year" class="date_class">
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
     ....
</select>
```

Вот так пытаюсь получить в Mootols, но не срабатывает. Как правильно получить массив значений в переменную?

```
var birthdate = $contactForm.getElement('select[name="birthdate"]').getProperty('value');
```

Comment: На сервер нужно будет передать в формате json.

Answer (score 1):

Для удобства обернем ваши `SELECT` еще в `DIV`.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <select name="birthdate[day]" id="birthdate-day" class="date_class">
        <option value="0"> </option>
         .....
    </select>
    <select name="birthdate[month]" id="birthdate-month"     class="date_class">
        <option value="0"></option>
        ..........
    </select>
    <select name="birthdate[year]" id="birthdate-year" class="date_class">
        <option value="0"> </option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
         ....
    </select>
</div>
```

а для считывания можно использовать такой скрипт:

```
function (element) {
    var elements = jQuery('select', element);
    var result = {};
    jQuery.each(elements, function (item, element) {
        element = jQuery(element);
        var name = window.namespace + element.attr('name');
        result[name] = element.val();
    })
    return result;
}
```

и на выходе мы получаем массив типа: `{name:value}`.